# iOS (Swift) - Tabbed navigation on view controller

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, tabbed

So, My problems lies with the tabbed navigation bar (The bottom navigation bar with icons). Is there a way to make this static so that it shown on all view controllers/ screen, including ones that do not contain a main link.

If you check the image below, I have a view controller connected to tabbed navigation bar that displays that view controller icon. I then have another view controller connection to that view controller, and I would like to make the tabbed navigation bar show on this ...

Is this possible to do? I'm not sure if it requires code, or just adding a few things to the storyboard. Any advise would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

[The Storyboard of my application (I'm not important enough to embed images just yet :( )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl6k5.png)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are presenting the View Controllers with the "Push" method, and not the "Modal" method, the tab bar controller should stay at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I connected the ViewController's by pressing 'ctrl' and dragging to the controller I want to show. The Storyboard segue is set to 'Kind - Show (e.g. Push)).  @dan